# MongoDB: How to find by subdocument ID?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to model the concept of `games` where `teams` of `players` compete against each other in MongoDB.

I have two collections: `players` and `games`.

This is how a document in `games` looks like.

```
{
    "_id": { "$oid": "1" },
    "teams": [
        {
            "players": [
                {
                    "player": { "$oid": "2" },
                    "score": 500,
                },
                {
                    "player": { "$oid": "3" },
                    "score": 550,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "players": [
                {
                    "player": { "$oid": "4" },
                    "score": 500,
                },
                {
                    "player": { "$oid": "5" },
                    "score": 550,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the task: given a player ID I want to find all games in which this player participated.

What I've tried:

```
db.games.find( { "teams.players.player._id": "2" } )
```

However, this does not return anything.

By the way, I'm using Mongoose with the following schema:

```
playerSchema = Schema
    player: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' }
    score: { type: Number }

teamSchema = Schema
    players: [ playerSchema ]

gameSchema = Schema
    teams: [ teamSchema ]
```

with the following CoffeeScript query:

```
Game.find 'teams.players.player._id': playerId
```

which returns no results for any player ID.

Comment: If you guys think that the schema could be designed in a better way, I'd love to get some pointers, too!

Comment: Do you want two teams, or more than two? I can give a decent example for two teams but more teams is a little more tedious and involves additional fields for searching purposes.

Comment: It's just two teams. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your document:

```
"players": [
            {
                "player": { "$oid": "4" },
                "score": 500,
            },
            {
                "player": { "$oid": "5" },
                "score": 550,
            }
        ]
```

The `player` field in the embedded collection of `players` is a BSON Id (i.e. it looks something like `ObjectId("4e208e070347a90001000008")`), so I think you should structure your query like so:

```
db.games.find( { "teams.players.player": ObjectId("2") } )
```

Note, I've dropped the `_id` -- provided that works in a mongo console, then I suspect the Coffee query will be similar (drop the `_id` portion).

Comment: Like a charm, thank you! With mongoose it's even easier because it automatically converts the string into an object id: `Game.find 'teams.players.player': playerId`

Answer (score 2):

I used your feedback to restrict this example to a home and away team. Remember that Mongo is not a relational database and using relationships is often an indication of a relational-database mindset. Duplication is the key.

Instead of references from the game to specific player documents, I have stored the name of the player. I assume this is an immutable unique index. The player has been given a games array containing references to each game he played in. This is actually quite bad as we have to query again and populate this array. It would be better to store a name here as well, but since I don't know your situation I'm not sure if a game has an immutable representable name.

This basic idea has to be improved with error checking (e.g. middleware) but I leave that up to you.

```
// Schemas
var playerSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, index: true, unique: true},
    games: {type: [Schema.ObjectId], ref: 'Game'}
});

var gameSchema = new Schema({
    homeTeam: [{player: {name: String}, score: Number}]
    awayTeam: [{player: {name: String}, score: Number}]
});

// Models
var Player = mongoose.model('Player', playerSchema);
var Team = mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema);
var Game = mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);

// Middleware
gameSchema.post('save', function (game) {
    var addMatchToPlayer = function(name) {
        Player.findOne({name: name}, function(err, player) {
            if (!err && player && player.games.indexOf(game._id) === -1) {
                player.games.push(game._id);
                player.save();
            }
        });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < game.homeTeam.length; i++) {
        addMatchToPlayer(game.homeTeam[i].name);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < game.awayTeam.length; i++) {
        addMatchToPlayer(game.awayTeam[i].name);
    }
});

// Queries
Player.findOne({name: 'Roel van Uden'}).populate('games').exec(function (err, player) {
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! You're right, I definitely have been working with relational data for too long. There's still two things that bother me with your proposition: 1. what's the problem with using the object id as a reference to other documents? The name would not be immutable enough, but the id is guaranteed to be unique. 2. I don't like the idea that the relationship between games and players would be duplicated. I'm really afraid of creating inconsistencies this way. Am I being too SQL?

Comment: 1. It is expensive. MongoDB has no JOIN, thus simulating one requires at least two trips to the database. With trillions of records, SQL would become sluggish. MongoDB scales because you embed relevant data, thus pulling just one document, otherwise it will hit the same choke point. 2. Yes, since Mongo is not aware of your data, it cannot know about relationships and has no concept of validation and FK integrity. If you remain scared of inconsistencies, don't move from SQL, because SQL is amazing for exactly that set of features. NoSQL sacrifices a lot of convenience for amazing speed.

Comment: Roel, thanks for the explanations. I will consider these aspects. Do you have any reading tips?