# Finding Parent Doc from subdoc ID in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a `subdoc Id` and I need to return the `parent Doc` using `Mongoose` and `MongoDB`. I read here: [MongoDB: How to find by subdocument ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923508/mongodb-how-to-find-by-subdocument-id) that I should just be able to used    `Polls.find({'options': id}` but it is returning any empty array and not the appropriate document.

Schema

```
var Polls = new Schema({
    name: String,
    options: [{
        name: String,
        count: Number
    }]
}
```

Sample Poll

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "58ac963a8a84500de89c1080"
},
"name": "Here is one Poll",
"options": [
    {
        "name": "This is the first one",
        "count": 0,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "58ac963a8a84500de89c1083"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Second One",
        "count": 0,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "58ac963a8a84500de89c1082"
        }
    }
],
"__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are querying it wrong.

Try this:

```
Polls.find({'options._id': id},function(err,result){
    //result will be an array of matched document
    //result[i]._id will give you the parent id.
    //if there is only one such document, you can try : result[0]._id
});
```